# Why COM classes need constructor? How to use COM class without registration?

Tags: c++, com, directshow

I am looking into DirectShow samples from Windows SDK. Many of the classes feature non-default constructor. How those constructors are called? Who supplies arguments?

Can I use those classes in C++ programs without registration? If so I could use class constructor directly.

If I use a COM class without registration what happens in the following code fragment:

```
Foo * foo = new Foo(.....); // note, not using CoCreateInstance
Bar * bar = foo->QueryInterface(...);
bar->Release();
delete foo; // CRASH?
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't know how `Release` is implemented in the general case (it could even be a no-op, or use another memory allocator). Here, it is likely doing `delete this`. You should use `CoCreateInstance` + `Release`, this is the only safe thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `COM`, it is just the framework is built this way and constructor arguments in DirectShow BaseClasses are necessary to get everything together - the class, the ancestor, the instantiating factory.

Using COM class without registration might be or might not be possible. I suspect you might be interested in using DirectShow filter without registration instead, and there is a good article on the topic: [Using Filters Without Registration](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2011/June/UnregisteredFilters.htm).

Answer (score 2):

A C++ class that's exposed as a *real* COM coclass cannot in general have a constructor that takes arguments.  There's no mechanism for the COM client code to pass arguments to the CoCreateInstance() function.  A COM interface typically has an Initialize() method to supply required initialization.  Technically that can be doctored as well, CoCreateInstance is just a convenience function that hides the class factory (IClassFactory).  A custom class factory with a custom CreateInstance() method is possible, but rarely done.

Microsoft uses the interface-based programming model that's common in COM code in non-COM code as well.  DirectX is a good example.  Think of Direct3DCreate9Ex() as the class factory.